# Why did my shapefile (.shp) disappear?

Tags: shapefile

Why did my shapefile disappear and how can I recover it? It was the only folder that I saved the data for my project. Now when I wanted to get access to the shapefile, it showed me that there is no shapefile (.shp component) and there are other components (.shx/.dbf/.prj/...) under my folder.

[image: directory listing]

Comment: Use ArcCatalog when you need to copy and paste otherwise if you copy and paste in Windows Explorer and it is easy to get lost one of the files.. Also make a backup copies when you do like this.

Comment: Thanks. I will that from now. Do you think it is possible to recover the geometry somehow? There is an shp.xml file. The other option I see is to use a recovery file software, but not sure but it.

Comment: You can try and see if you could use the System Restore to get that shapefile back.. Don't know if that is possibility

Comment: The .shp.xml is just metadata, it has no geometry beyond an envelope of the data extent. It's generally possible to regenerate the `.shx` component, but not a missing `.shp`. It's time recover from your most recent backup (**all** files must be recovered together).

Answer (score 3):

What we call a "Shapefile" is a combination of several files, as you can see. The .shp, .shx and .dbf files are mandatory. Otherwise the "shapefile" is broken.

Did you move those "shapefiles" after their creation? If so, know that they must move all together at once, or don't move them at all. Otherwise, this happens.

The .shp is the geometry itself. So if it somehow disappeared, you can't do anything with the "shapefile".

All those files that are the "shapefile" have the same filename with a different extension. So try searching for that filename on the computer.

Comment: Thanks.
I did move (from disk D to C) all the folder with all the data inside, meaning that shp extension file was also inside as in the original folder location, which work correctly while adding data or opening the project. So i wonder why moving folder location make me loose the geometry data (and not all the rest). It might be broken and unrecoverable right? Still..don´t have issue why this happen like that...

Comment: Windows won't move open files. It will warn you about this. If you then deleted the source directory, the file is likely unrecoverable.